# SQL count a value for each userID record except where one record value of userId is x

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery

I got so stuck I do now know how to formulate my question so I created a hypothetical scenario with my wanted result.

I am trying to create a query that counts the amount of fruits per userID exept for the userID that has a record where fruit is Banana.

```
+----------+--------+--------------+
| recordID | userId |    Fruit     |
+----------+--------+--------------+
|        0 |    112 | Apple        |
|        1 |    112 | Banana       |
|        2 |    112 | kiwi         |
|        - |      - | -            |
|        3 |    113 | Banana       |
|        4 |    113 | Pear         |
|        - |      - | -            |
|        5 |    114 | Dragon fruit |
|        6 |    114 | Pineapple    |
|        - |      - | -            |
|        7 |    115 | Dragon Fruit |
|        8 |    115 | Cherry       |
+----------+--------+--------------+
```

wanted result:

```
+-------+-------------+--+
| count |    fruit    |  |
+-------+-------------+--+
|     2 | dragonfruit |  |
|     1 | pineapple   |  |
|     1 | cherry      |  |
+-------+-------------+--+
```

ignoring user with UserId 113 because it has a record for fruit with value Banana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a filtering clause:

```
select fruit, count(*)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.userid = t.userid and t2.fruit = 'banana'
                 )
group by fruit
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `not in` and sub-query

```
select count(*),fruit from
(
select * from t where userid not in(

select userId from t where Fruit='Banana'
)
) t1 group by fruit
```